# android cant get facebook profile picutre

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

Im trying to implement login with facebook in android , im getting the email and name correctly but i cant get the profile picture

here is the code

```
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    println(loginResult)
                    val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.accessToken
                    ) { `object`, response ->
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString())

                        // Application code
                        val id = `object`.getString("id")
                        val email = `object`.getString("email")
                        val name = `object`.getString("name")

                        val picture = `object`.getString("picture")
                        Picasso.get().load(picture).into(image_view)

//                        registerRequest(email,name)
                    }
                    val parameters = Bundle()
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.type(large)")
                    request.parameters = parameters
                    request.executeAsync()
                }
```

i have tried this also but its also not working

```
Picasso.get().load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "picture?/type=normal").into(image_view)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
 val profilePicture =
               URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + jsonObject.getString("id") + "/picture?width=200&height=200")
```

also put an empty check before load into Picasso or Glide

Comment: what do you mean by empty check ?

Comment: it gives an error on the picasso statment "none of the following functions can be called with arguments suplied"

Comment: add
if(profilePicture.toString().isNotEmpty())
{     
       then load  profilePicture.toString() to Picasso 
 }

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure you have the necessary permission from Facebook to read the user's profile picture and then make the request for it passing the access token you received when you successfully logged in using Facebook's LoginManager as a URL parameter. (I'm supposing you're using the Facebook Login SDK for Android)

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() + 
        "?access_token=" + 
            facebookLoginResult.getAccessToken().getToken())
    .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testing));
```

Make sure you're using HTTPS